# How to get active users of my own web page via facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook

I know we can get online users, but this online is not what I want, I want to know the online users who are currently on my web page, but not facebook. I want to get the user list who is now using my web page after log in using their facebook account, and then I don't care whether they are still active on their facebook.
Is there any methods that I can get this information? Please help!
 I am using Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the API that lets you know whether one user is active/online on your app.

You would need to record connections by yourself. But you are using Javascript, which is a client-side language. It means that it is executed on the client's browser and that you won't be able to manage incoming connections.

Are you using PHP (server-side) in the background? That would make it possible for you to display the connected people for the last 5 minutes!